# How select rows where certain columns have one of the largest values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe and want to select rows where certain column is in 2 largest values. Output should show rows where 'duration' is 50 and 45

I tried

```
data = {
  "production": [420, 380, 390],
  "duration": [50, 40, 45]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df[df['production'] == df['production'].nlargest(2)]
```

> ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Comment: kindly provide sample dataframe with expected output

Comment: The question is updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TRY:

```
result = df[df['production'].isin(df['production'].nlargest(2))]
```

Or if you want all the population that lies within these 2 values:

```
result = df[df['production'].between(*df['production'].nlargest(2).values[::-1])]
```